# 502 Bad Gateway error from nginx/1.22.1 when I refresh the page

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect, keycloak-angular

I am using Angular and Django, and I'm encountering an issue with Keycloak for authentication. The problem is that I can log in normally, but when I refresh the page, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error from nginx/1.22.1

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
GET

scheme
https
host
keycloak-hugo.snow.tb.rns.equant.com
filename
/realms/INSIDE_LAB_Tool/protocol/openid-connect/auth
client_id
angular-front
redirect_uri
http://localhost:4200/inventory/ipv4Subnet#iss=https://keycloak-hugo.snow.tb.rns.equant.com/realms/INSIDE_LAB_Tool
state
54aa267c-cea5-4544-a784-19f6c3b24417
response_mode
fragment
response_type
code
scope
openid
nonce
939a0363-f321-405e-af58-04fb1c649df1
Adresse
10.253.52.24:443
État
502
Bad Gateway
VersionHTTP/2
Transfert353 o (taille 157 o)
Politique de référentstrict-origin-when-cross-origin
Priorité de la requêteHighest

content-length
157
content-type
text/html
date
Mon, 15 Jan 2024 14:28:35 GMT
server
nginx/1.22.1
strict-transport-security
max-age=63072000
X-Firefox-Spdy
h2

Accept
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection
keep-alive
Cookie
AUTH_SESSION_ID=f2c7e4bc-da84-41f9-a51b-f87c4a305d4c.keycloak-7bd97bc4cc-68s7j-64592; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=f2c7e4bc-da84-41f9-a51b-f87c4a305d4c.keycloak-7bd97bc4cc-68s7j-64592; KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICI0NTMzOTFkZC0xMDYzLTRmNWItOGNlYy0yMDQ3ZTBlYmYxZTYifQ.eyJleHAiOjE3MDUzNjQ4NDIsImlhdCI6MTcwNTMyODg0MiwianRpIjoiNGExYzdiMTEtYTc0ZC00NTNmLWFhZWEtYzdiNjIyMWRlYzQ2IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9rZXljbG9hay1odWdvLnNub3cudGIucm5zLmVxdWFudC5jb20vcmVhbG1zL0lOU0lERV9MQUJfVG9vbCIsInN1…R5cCI6IlNlcmlhbGl6ZWQtSUQiLCJzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXRlIjoiZjJjN2U0YmMtZGE4NC00MWY5LWE1MWItZjg3YzRhMzA1ZDRjIiwic2lkIjoiZjJjN2U0YmMtZGE4NC00MWY5LWE1MWItZjg3YzRhMzA1ZDRjIiwic3RhdGVfY2hlY2tlciI6IkpydGMxanhjMWNXWFBPQ1BkSlozUUNaZWFwZzBhTmtwdHBMMndqSnFaTjgifQ.hXvlLVYMw6OE5kh2-83yQMSHvaEPQX7M00bdKffiDuc; KEYCLOAK_SESSION=INSIDE_LAB_Tool/8f4160bd-db1d-45ba-aaca-e891cde8b8ba/f2c7e4bc-da84-41f9-a51b-f87c4a305d4c; KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY=INSIDE_LAB_Tool/8f4160bd-db1d-45ba-aaca-e891cde8b8ba/f2c7e4bc-da84-41f9-a51b-f87c4a305d4c
DNT
1
Host
keycloak-hugo.snow.tb.rns.equant.com
Referer
http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest
document
Sec-Fetch-Mode
navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site
cross-site
TE
trailers
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests
1
User-Agent
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

Angular keycloak django

K8s docker

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.